# NPM error while installing packages for twilio flex plugins

Tags: node.js, npm, plugins, bootstrap-4, twilio

I am having an error while installing NPM Packages or running the script `npm start`

> Can you please help me to solve the problem
>   [Here is the errors detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw1ua.png)

Here are the Log details, sent to `.npm/_logs`

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/irfan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/irfan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'i'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v14.2.0
4 verbose npm-session 24b8946923194204
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
7 info lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~preinstall: plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 2419ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 21ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1603ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
17 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 1781ms
18 timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 4100ms
19 silly currentTree plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
19 silly currentTree ├── @babel/code-frame@7.8.3
.
.
.
20 silly idealTree ├── xmlchars@2.2.0
20 silly idealTree ├── xmlhttprequest@1.8.0
20 silly idealTree ├── xregexp@4.3.0
20 silly idealTree ├── xtend@4.0.2
20 silly idealTree ├── y18n@4.0.0
20 silly idealTree ├── yallist@2.1.2
20 silly idealTree ├── yaml@1.9.2
20 silly idealTree ├── yargs-parser@13.1.2
20 silly idealTree └─┬ yargs@13.3.2
20 silly idealTree   └── string-width@3.1.0
21 silly install generateActionsToTake
22 timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 214ms
23 silly diffTrees action count 0
24 silly decomposeActions action count 0
25 silly install executeActions
26 silly doSerial global-install 0
27 verbose correctMkdir /Users/irfan/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
28 verbose lock using /Users/irfan/.npm/_locks/staging-bec3f2539599f485.lock for /Users/irfan/Desktop/Projects/Clients/Twilio Flex/plugin-getting-started/node_modules/.staging
29 silly doParallel extract 0
30 silly doReverseSerial unbuild 0
31 silly doSerial remove 0
32 silly doSerial move 0
33 silly doSerial finalize 0
34 silly doParallel refresh-package-json 0
35 silly doParallel preinstall 0
36 silly doSerial build 0
37 silly doSerial global-link 0
38 silly doParallel update-linked 0
39 silly doSerial install 0
40 silly doSerial postinstall 0
41 verbose unlock done using /Users/irfan/.npm/_locks/staging-bec3f2539599f485.lock for /Users/irfan/Desktop/Projects/Clients/Twilio Flex/plugin-getting-started/node_modules/.staging
42 timing stage:executeActions Completed in 14ms
43 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
44 silly install runPostinstallTopLevelLifecycles
45 silly build plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
46 info linkStuff plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
47 silly linkStuff plugin-getting-started@0.0.0 has /Users/irfan/Desktop/Projects/Clients/Twilio Flex as its parent node_modules
48 silly install plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
49 info lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~install: plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
50 silly postinstall plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
51 info lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~postinstall: plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
52 verbose lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
53 verbose lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~postinstall: PATH: /Users/irfan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/irfan/Desktop/Projects/Clients/Twilio Flex/plugin-getting-started/node_modules/.bin:/Users/irfan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/irfan/utils/flutter/bin
54 verbose lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~postinstall: CWD: /Users/irfan/Desktop/Projects/Clients/Twilio Flex/plugin-getting-started
55 silly lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~postinstall: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run bootstrap' ]
56 silly lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~postinstall: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
57 info lifecycle plugin-getting-started@0.0.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
58 verbose stack Error: plugin-getting-started@0.0.0 postinstall: `npm run bootstrap`
58 verbose stack Exit status 1
58 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/Users/irfan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
58 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
58 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/Users/irfan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
58 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
58 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
58 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
59 verbose pkgid plugin-getting-started@0.0.0
60 verbose cwd /Users/irfan/Desktop/Projects/Clients/Twilio Flex/plugin-getting-started
61 verbose Darwin 19.3.0
62 verbose argv "/Users/irfan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/irfan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin/npm" "i"
63 verbose node v14.2.0
64 verbose npm  v6.14.4
65 error code ELIFECYCLE
66 error errno 1
67 error plugin-getting-started@0.0.0 postinstall: `npm run bootstrap`
67 error Exit status 1
68 error Failed at the plugin-getting-started@0.0.0 postinstall script.
68 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
69 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly the same problem, but I had a similar issue. In my case, it was a mismatch in the versions of **webpack** called for in **craco-config-flex-plugin** and **react-scripts**.

I ran the command to install **create-flex-plugin** again with **npm install -g create-flex-plugin**, then went through the steps to create my plugin again, and it wored.